# How to use for loop to find NA values of each column of a data set

Tags: r, for-loop, na

df is "node.all.final" and variables (columns) are "ccode", "stateName", "year", "access.electricity", "control.corruption" ....

my repetitive codes to find NAs and trying to see which country gets NAs in which year:

```
na.node <- node.all.final[is.na(node.all.final$access.electricity), ] #access.electricity"
```

```
    unique(na.node$stateName)
```

```
    na.node$year
```

```
na.node <- node.all.final[is.na(node.all.final$control.corruption), ] #control.corruption
```

```
    unique(na.node$stateName)
```

```
    na.node$year
```

I actually need to find which country in what year gets NAs from more than 40 variables. So how do I simply my codes by using for loop or any other potential ways to reach this goal?

I use is.na to subset each variable and find NAs in a variable and then identify which country in what years.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We could loop over the columns that are not 'stateName', 'year', get the logical index of `NA` (`is.na`) to subset the 'stateName', 'year' columns in a `list`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(node.all.final), c("stateName", "year"))
lapply(node.all.final[nm1], function(x) 
      node.all.final[is.na(x), c("stateName", "year")])
```